# How iOS Apps in objective c Adapts to the iPhone mobile version Screen Size

Tags: ios

How iOS Apps in objective c Adapts to the iPhone mobile version Screen Size. 
I developing simple in objective c. my application has not have same size when I tested  different simulators. after searching I get there is issue in iPhone mobile size:

**iPhone Mobile Resolutions and Display Specifications**

[image: iphone mobileResolutions and Display Specifications]

can any one help me.

Comment: can you please share different  screenshots for understanding purpose.

Comment: Them to yuhjjnm inni jikuniinjum mjiiiimiumikiniijkim

Answer (score 0):

The apps in iOS irrespective of the language (swift or obj-c) adapts to the screen size automatically. Depending upon the target device, you are provided with a screen size which you can access using `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds` to know the screen size of the app.

But you actually don't need to know what screensize you are running your app on as far as you are developing your UI flexible enough to accommodate all the screen sizes.

If you are new to the platform [Building Adaptive UI](https://developer.apple.com/design/adaptivity/) provides a great number of resources for the topic.

[This autolayout tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/160527/auto-layout-tutorial-ios-11-getting-started) can be a good starting point for supporting various screen sizes.